# Jenkins with GCP ephemeral agents take much longer to start agent with declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gcp

We have a jenkins instance using ephemeral agents in gcp. We use container image to build in. Our existing pipeline (scripted and setup via gui) takes about 5-10 seconds to spin up an agent and start building.

Now we created and equivalent declarative pipeline in git. It works as expected but it takes about 3-5 minutes to get the agent running and start building.

Unfortunately I have limited access to debug the issue. Our infrastructure team insists there should be no difference.

Has anyone had similar issues?